# Integrate a chatbot (using php, aiml 1.0, program-O) onto a website written in .NET

Tags: php, .net, aiml

We have a chatbot written in aiml 1.0 using program-O as the interpreter, basically we used PHP, ajax. Now we want this to be integrated onto a website which is in .Net environment. Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Integrating different technologies isn't too difficult, if you are able to make adjustments in both languages then using JSON from the browser to your PHP chat backend could easily work.

However, if you do not want to expose your PHP application directly to the end user, then an application to application interface would work as well. For example JSON, SOAP, REST are all good API protocols to use.